# Is this physical model exactly solvable?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, mathematical-physics, mathematical-modeling, quantum-mechanics

There exists a popular model in the Physics of heavy quark bound systems, called the [*Cornell potential model*](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.21.203), in which the inter-quark potential is modeled to vary with radial distance $r$ as

$$V(r) = - \frac{\kappa}{r} + \frac{r}{a^2}$$

The mathematical problem is reduced to solving the radial part of the Schrodinger equation

$$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \frac{d^2 u}{dr^2} + \left[ V(r) + \frac{l(l+1)}{2mr^2}\right]u = Eu$$

for the above potential, hence obtaining the reduced wavefunction $u(r)$.

- The reduced wavefunction $u(r)$ is subject to the boundary conditions $u(r=0) = 0$, and $u'(r=0) = R(0) =$ some number $C$.
- Each of the constants $\hbar$, $m$, $\kappa$, and $a$ are positive numbers.
- $l$ serves the role of azimuthal quantum number, and can take non-negative integer values, i.e. $l = 0, 1, 2, 3 \ldots$ However, this is generally fed in as a constant input, and choice of $l$ segregates solutions into various categories, e.g. $l=0$ states are the $s-$wave states, $l=1$ are the $p-$wave states, and so on.
- The energy eigenvalue $E$ can, in general, be either positive (called a *Scattering State* solution), or negative (called a *Bound State* solution); however, in this case, we are concerned with the latter variety ($E<0$) since the model caters precisely to bound heavy-quark systems.

Scanning across the literature, one only finds (abundantly) numerical/iterative approaches applied to this mathematical problem, and Wolfram Alpha also succumbs before it.

My questions are:

- Is this physical model exactly solvable, i.e. is there any general solution to this differential equation for $u(r)$, for any $E<0$?
- If not, what is the exact problem with this potential which hinders reaching an exact solution. (*I say that because the singularity at $r=0$ is due to inverse $r$ part, but if the second term was missing from the potential, then the pure inverse $r$ potential is known to be exactly solvable, it is a textbook problem taught in all undergraduate Physics courses.*)
- Aside from numerical/iterative approaches, if there is any alternative method which can be used for this purpose, or can be used in circumventing this difficulty?

Comment: I'm not familiar with either quantum mechanics or differential equations, but the given differential equation can be rewritten to
$$\frac{d^2 u}{dr^2}=\frac{2m}{(a\hbar)^2}\left(\frac{r^3-a^2Er^2-a^2\kappa r+\tfrac{a^2l(l+1)}{2}}{r^2}\right)u$$
so setting
$$C:=\frac{2m}{(a\hbar)^2},\qquad c_0:=a^2\binom{l}{2},\qquad c_1:=-a^2\kappa,\qquad c_2:=-a^2E,$$
this becomes
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=C\frac{x^3+c_2x^2+c_1x+c}{x^2}y.$$
And this looks like something mathematicians have thought a lot about.

Comment: Well, by setting some constants equal to a other constant we can rewrite your problem in the following sense:

$$\alpha\cdot x''(t)+x(t)\cdot\left(\eta\cdot t-\rho\cdot\frac{1}{t}+\beta\cdot\frac{1}{t^2}\right)=\gamma\cdot x(t)\tag1$$

We can rewrite equation $(1)$ as follows:

$$\frac{x''(t)}{x(t)}=\frac{\gamma-\eta\cdot t+\rho\cdot\frac{1}{t}-\beta\cdot\frac{1}{t^2}}{\alpha}\tag2$$

Comment: @Servaes - Thanks. That's what brings me here. So, why is everyone doing numerical solutions if analytic solutions exist? Or if they don't exist, why don't they exist? That's precisely the crux of my question. :)

Comment: @Jan - Thanks. Does it lead us further somewhere, maybe to a class of equations whose solution is well documented?

Comment: Here's a start: For $f:=e^{\sqrt{c_2}x}$ and $g:=\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}x}{a}\right)^{l+1}$ we have
$$\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}=c_2f
\qquad\text{ and }\qquad
\frac{d^2g}{dx^2}=\frac{c_0}{x^2}g,$$
so for $z:=y-(f+g)$ we have
$$\frac{d^2z}{dx^2}=C\left(x+\frac{c_1}{x}\right)z.$$
I haven't done differential equations since my first year in uni (over a decade ago), but I'm sure people have come up with a trick to solve this.

Comment: @Servaes - That's an interesting transformation. I'll try to see if it leads me anywhere, but I am also very rusty. Also, in the meantime, someone more mathematically-adept (and less-rusty than me) can perhaps take it further. It would be very startling if it does admit an exact solution, it will make a lot of particle physicists look silly! (However, that's not my goal, to be very clear.) Thanks a lot for your very helpful inputs. :)

Comment: I'm glad (and surprised) I could help. I wouldn't call it a transformation myself, rather a partial solution; by linearity of taking derivatives it suffices to solve the differential equations
$$\frac{d^2y_1}{dx^2}=Cx,\qquad
\frac{d^2y_0}{dx^2}=Cc_2,\qquad
\frac{d^2y_{-1}}{dx^2}=Cc_1x^{-1}
\qquad\text{ and }\qquad
\frac{d^2y_{-2}}{dx^2}=Cc_0x^{-2},$$
and then $y=y_1+y_0+y_{-1}+y_{-2}$ is a solution to the differential equation
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=C\frac{x^3+c_2x^2+c_1x+c_0}{x^2}y,$$
that I 'reduced' your original one to. I just solved for $y_0$ and $y_{-2}$ in my previous comment.

Comment: @Servaes - Thanks, There would also be $y_i$ terms on the RHS, but that notwithstanding, if I simply substitute $y = y_{-2} + y_{-1} + y_0 + y_1$ in the equation wrote at the end, it doesn't give back those 4 equations. Am I missing something? e.g. The equation for $y_1$ would cover all four powers of $x$, if I am not wrong. :)

Comment: @Servaes: Your insights and comments are interesting. I suggest you summarize them and give a partial answer. It may lead someone to a more complete answer.

Comment: You're right; I was too eager to simplify! Goes to show I shouldn't burn my fingers on calculus ;) It turns out even the simple differential equations I mentioned (for $y_1$ and $y_{-1}$) are nasty; their solutions are the [Airy and Airy Bi functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function) and [modified Bessel functions of the first and second kinds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1). But your full differential equation seems much farther from allowing a description; I'm surprised again at the horrors of differential equations!

Comment: @Servaes - No issues. Thanks for your inputs, nevertheless. :)

Comment: No, it is, of course, not [solvable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_quantum-mechanical_systems_with_analytical_solutions#Solvable_systems). Asking for a reason is opinion-based: you want speculation on why nobody succeeded. I gather you have exhausted [this](https://www.degruyter.com/downloadpdf/j/phys.2015.13.issue-1/phys-2015-0012/phys-2015-0012.pdf) one.

Comment: @CosmasZachos - Thanks for the links. Yes, I have read that 2015 article, but that's still within the category of numerical/iterative approaches itself. I am not asking for speculation, I am asking at what point do we hit a roadblock, and what is the exact roadblock. That's because the contrary to what one might guess, the singular part of the potential is an exact solvable model.

Comment: Each piece of the potential is solvable, but the sum is not. There is no roadblock: there is no road.